# Import oracle multiple dump files

Tags: oracle, import, export

I have multiple dmp files exported from an Oracle database with datapump using the parallel=4 option.

I'm on a standard edition so I can't use the parallel option, can I import the dump files anyway on my oracle using the command:

```
impdp system@oracletest schemas=<schema_name> exclude=user:\"='usename'\" directory=<dir_path> dumpfile='file01.dmp,file02.dmp,file03.dmp,file04.dmp,file05.dmp,file06.dmp'
```

The parallel option used for the export, has to be used also for the import?

The database contains multiple schemas inside and I want to import just one for now.

Comment: What happened when you tried? Did you get an error, or something else suggesting it didn't work?

Comment: No I didn't try before being sure to not break anything

Comment: I don't think having a dump file created with parallel option results in it automatically being imported in parallel - you'd still have to set the PARALLEL=3 flag in your import job...which will get ignored or error out in stand edition - i'm with @Alex-poole, just try it